# Store and Search Stock Symbols AWS Architecture - Elasticsearch or DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-dynamodb, aws-elasticsearch

I have an external API to synchronize all the Stock Symbols from all markets (NASDAQ, NYSE...).
I have an AWS Lambda to get this data from the external API.

Then I want a frontend website with a search bar, where the user can type **"Tes"** and it should appear automatically some suggestions, just like **"Tesla"** or **"TESO"** or other companies starting with "Tes".

My doubt is in Backend. Where should I store these symbols? in DynamoDB or ElasticSearch?
Do you know of another AWS service that is better suited for this scenario?

I was thinking in store in DynamoDb, using the symbol as Primary Key, but then we cannot search by "Tes" without a full scan. With Elasticsearch I don't have experience.

Comment: Why will someone downgrade my post? Is it his question or mine?

Answer (score 2):

Opensearch is what you need, which is also serverless now which makes it a good fit for serverless architectures. Using DynamoDB streams, you can easily stream data into OpenSearch. Code pointers here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/integrations.html

And [this workshop](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/12e10797-c203-464a-9872-2231bf1b7d97/en-US/workshop_overview/) will provide you with the necessary information and tools to be successful.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I just created an OpenSearch service with default configurations. The only issue, now I have a bill of 53$, with just 2 or 3 days of use.
I didn't notice that is so expensive

Resume, is exaclty what I need but pretty expensive just for a search suggestion (sadly)

Answer (score -1):

For transient data, consider using [AWS ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/). It's a key value store that runs on top of Redis or Memcached. You can use the symbol as key and store the running stock price as value.

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to non AWS services, I would recommend typesense of meilisearch. They are much better products for this use case than Elasticsearh is.